# Remove table but not delete form and fileds with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `HTML` form inside table i want to get rid that table completely and want to add `form` and `fields` inside a `div` i want to do this with jQuery any body have a way to do this?
Here is the my current code.

```html
<div class="widgetGuts shortcode">
    <form action="" method="post" id="frm-subscriptionFront" novalidate="">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="required">
                    <th>
                        <label for="frm-email" class="required"></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="frm-email" required="" value="" class="text form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address here">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td>        
                        <input type="submit" name="_submit" class="subscribeButton button" value="Subscribe">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_form_" value="subscriptionFront">
            <!--[if IE]>
                <input type=IEbug disabled style="display:none">
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the example of code how i want.

```html
<div class="widgetGuts shortcode">
    <form action="" method="post" id="frm-subscriptionFront" novalidate="">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="frm-email" required="" value="" class="text form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address here">
        <input type="submit" name="_submit" class="subscribeButton button" value="Subscribe">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_form_" value="subscriptionFront">
            <!--[if IE]>
                <input type=IEbug disabled style="display:none">
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can you not amend the HTML directly? Using jQuery in this manner to hack around the UI is not a very good idea.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This code is generated by a wordpress plugin and its very difficult to catch that `HTML` that why i want to follow this way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple using jquery:

```js
var form = $('#frm-subscriptionFront');

form.prepend(form.find('input'));
form.find('table').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widgetGuts shortcode">
    <form action="" method="post" id="frm-subscriptionFront" novalidate="">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="required">
                    <th>
                        <label for="frm-email" class="required"></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="frm-email" required="" value="" class="text form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address here">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="_submit" class="subscribeButton button" value="Subscribe">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_form_" value="subscriptionFront">
            <!--[if IE]>
                <input type=IEbug disabled style="display:none">
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#frm-subscriptionFront table').replaceWith( $('td > *, th > *') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ptapy47b/1

Edit to clarify: it will replace the table with the contents of `td` and `th` elements, so all the elements from the table will end up in your form, not just `input` elements. Which is IMO a good idea.